# Strange Modulus Operator Result - PHP

Tags: php, modulus

I am working on a PHP application and mathematical operation was resulting wrong answer which was displaying wrong results. So, I started digging down and after few hours effort I was able to detect the issue.

Here is the problematic **Expression:**

```
echo -1 % 26;
```

The answer should be `25` but it gives `-1`. I don't know, is there anything wrong with my expression?

**PHP Output:**
[image: PHP Output]

**Calculator:**
[image: Calculator Output]

Can anyone please identify, where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour. [From the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

> The result of the modulo operator % has the same sign as the dividend — that is, the result of `$a % $b` will have the same sign as `$a`

If the sign of the dividend (the part to the left of the `%`) changes, the result will also change. You can find the positive equivalent of a negative remainder by adding the divisor. -1 is equivalent to 25 modulo 26 since -1 + 26 = 25.

Hence you can do the following to get the positive result:

```
function modulo($dividend, $divisor) {
  $result = $dividend % $divisor;
  return $result < 0 ? $result + $divisor : $result;
}

$calculation = modulo(-1, 26); // 25
$calculation2 = modulo(51, 26); // 25
```

Comment: it is not about sign, result are also different

Comment: @Alena Answer updated to show why this is the case :)

Comment: thanks but I don't think if this is the proper way to handle it. Because I would need to add extra check, if number is negative then add it instead of calculating modulus.

Comment: @Alena updated again to add function which you can use and handles the negatives for you.

Answer (score 0):

How about ?

```
$ cat test.php
<?php

function truemod($num, $mod) {
  return ($mod + ($num % $mod)) % $mod;
}

echo truemod(-1, 26).PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Output

```
$ php test.php 
25
```

Comment: it works for this but causes problem with other calculation. But anyway, thanks!